# How to get count of checked categories using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Friends, We are having an array categories of scope variable. Need to get count of checked(checked: true) categories without using for loop. Is there any way? Please suggest. Thanx.

```
 $scope.categories = [
                       {categoryId : '1', checked: true}, 
                       {categoryId : '2', checked: true},         
                       {categoryId : '3', checked: false}, 
                       {categoryId : '4', checked: false}
                    ];
```

Comment: I think you have you { and [ mixed up.

Comment: Why don't you want a for loop?  Anything you use will be using one in the background.

Comment: Can you give how you want to use this count or some more information what is your need and why you don't want to use loop. Personally I don't think there is way to avoid loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you don't want to loop, however don't explain why? I don't think you can avoid a loop if you have an unknown length of array. In your case, a `filter` may do the trick.

**Update for clarity**
This will use a loop in the background.

```
var count = $scope.categories.filter(function(cat) { 
    return cat.checked === true 
}).length;
```

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion simon..Just I removed true
var count = $scope.categories.filter(function(cat) { 
    return cat.checked
}).length;

Comment: No problem :) - The `=== true` part only serves to ensure the checked property is `true` and not some other *truthy* value.

Comment: Yeah, it really is looping still, you just don't see that it is. Filter means loop over this array, apply the function to each element and return the element if the function returns true.

Comment: I know, but I suspect the OP just didn't want to use a `for` loop for some reason. Even though `filter` may in the background.

Comment: I assumed that you knew based on your answer.. just making sure the OP does.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is:

```
 $scope.categories = [
                      {categoryId : '1', checked: true}, 
                      {categoryId : '2', checked: true},         
                      {categoryId : '3', checked: false}, 
                      {categoryId : '4', checked: false}
                     ];

var total = $scope.categories.reduce(function(t,item){
                return t + +item.checked;
            },0)
```

Comment: This and simonlchilds answers are both equally valid, but this answer is using the right tool for what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid using any kind of loop you have to know the amount of items in your array in advance.

Assuming your example is fixed data, then you can simply use this

`var count = $scope.categories[0].checked + $scope.categories[1].checked + $scope.categories[2].checked + $scope.categories[3].checked`

to get the count. Any other solution will use a loop of some sort.

> In computer programming, a loop is a sequence of instruction s that is continually repeated until a certain condition is reached.

Comment: Well, without using ANY loop you probably have to assume a fixed amount of items in an array... else you will always end up using some kind of loop ;)

Comment: You are correct but I am wrong that mentioned small array of elements. If it is big, this is very difficult todo.

Comment: And that is where loops come in handy ;)

Comment: +1 for the clarity. I like this solution, despite the fact that this would be a fairly poor design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore/lodash:

```
var count = _.filter($scope.categories, {checked: true}).length;
```

Comment: Your suggestion also correct. Working fine like Simon suggestion. Thanx Tim